# Best keyboard layout for a programmer?

Tags: programming-languages, keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An Ideal Keyboard Layout for Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306423/an-ideal-keyboard-layout-for-programming)

As a programmer I don't type as much human language as normal users. In fact, **a lot** of what I type are ASCII special characters such as `$();:?=+-'"\[]{}<>`. Needless to say, QWERTY is not good at programming.

```
function decode($t)
{
    return preg_replace('/&lt;(\/)?('.tuh::$tags.')&gt;/i','<\1\2>',$t);
}
```

So I'm thinking about trying other layouts like [Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455525/is-the-switch-to-dvorak-worth-it) or [Colemak](http://colemak.com/), but they don't seem to be much better (Even the [programming](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) versions). So is there one that actually places the common keys right there next to the home row? No more stretching for each `$` or `]`?

Comment: Nitpick: the `$();:?=+-'"\[]{}<>` characters aren't *that* special in the sense that they all fall in the lower 7 bits of ASCII. Also, I'm pretty sure you meant "QWERTY".

Comment: This question is better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: qwerty not good for programming? Luxury! The []{}\ characters are all wrist-killing "Alt Gr" combos on the azerty keyboards used here in Belgium.

Comment: Subjective and argumentative imho.

Comment: Dvorak probably isn't any better at symbols, but it's a lot easier on my wrists for typing text, and (except when I'm playing around in APL!) most of what I type for source code is still letters.  When I used QWERTY, I ended up typing a lot less documentation because it was slower and more painful.  I'd be curious to see a histogram of actual character usage for programmers.  I suspect vowels would still win.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd still say qwerty just because; at least in my job; I use a number of different keyboards/computers during the day and the adjustment can be rough moving across.

Comment: I used Dvorak for a couple of years, and ended up back at Qwerty for this very reason.